# Single plan with multiple JWKS resolver

Tags: jwt, realm, keycloak, gravitee

I recently started exploring the [Gravitee API Platform](https://gravitee.io).

One thing that I was trying to do was configuring a single plan to validate incoming JWT tokens from multiple Keycloak realms.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Did you try anything? Where is the proof?

Comment: Yes and I recently oppened an issue on the Gravitee Github repo: https://github.com/gravitee-io/issues/issues/4859